# what's the event does the root viewcontroller get when a viewcontroller unload

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a project inwhich the root controller call multi viewcontrollers.
What is the even what's the event does the root viewcontroller get when a viewcontroller unload?

Do I need to construct even by myself?

Best Regards

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use viewwilldisappear to achieve what you are going for

Comment: when the viewcontroller exit, it will change a parameter.

how to notify the root controller the modifcation of the value and do relevant operation?

Comment: You should be introducing that view as a modalviewcontroller with the delegate of that view being the rootviewcontroller. When the parameter is changed in the modalviewcontroller it should call a method in the delegate (in this case your rootviewcontroller) like this: [self.parentViewController doSomething];